# Symfony 2 SonataAdminBundle - empty sources

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have installed SonataAdminBundle by next guide: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/installation.html.

But when I run admin panel css and js sources don't upload on page.

```
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css  dashboard:8
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css  dashboard:10
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.css  dashboard:14
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2-bootstrap.css  dashboard:15
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css  dashboard:9
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js  dashboard:31
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.scrollTo.min.js:7
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js  dashboard:34
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:29
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.min.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-i18n.min.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.form.js:818
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.confirmExit.js:43
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-editable.min.js:5
GET http://192.168.1.25/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.min.js  dashboard:41
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined App.js:15
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Admin.js:12
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined treeview.js:108
```

The folder ../project.com/web/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/ also comprises those files (command **php app/console assets:install web** don't help it):

```
├── js
├── select2
└── vendor
    ├── eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker
    │   ├── build
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   └── js
    │   └── src
    │       ├── js
    │       │   └── locales
    │       └── less
    └── moment
        ├── lang
        └── min
```

The composer.json require contains next:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "dev-master",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
        "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "umbrella-web/sf2-mailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "umbrella-web/markdown-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.1.*",
        "semantics3/semantics3-php": "dev-master",
        "bcc/resque-bundle": "dev-master",
        "league/color-extractor": " 0.1.*",
        "acts/sphinx-realtime-bundle": "dev-master",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "0.9.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev"
    },
```

Why I have this problem and how i can decide it?

Comment: What does the `require` line say in your `composer.json` file for Sonata Admin Bundle?

Comment: I added composer info in the post.

Comment: Change the line `"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",` to `"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",` and run `composer update` and then `php app/console assets:install web`

Comment: I did, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: @MikhailSchedrakov have you tried `php app/console assetic:dump` and then assets install?